# PHP How to call a method from a class while it is running?

Tags: php, class

I have a script in PHP doing some work forever.

```
<?php
require_once 'ClassA.php'; 
$a= new ClassA($param1, $param2);
$a->start();
$a->setColor("blue");
while (1) {
    echo $a->getColor();
}
?>
```

How can I change the color of $a oject when I receive a GET/POST requests?

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["color"])){
    $color= $_GET["color"];
    $a->setColor($color); <<<--- Something like this
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can't. PHP isn't "persistent". It'll run in response to **ONE** http request to your server. If another http request comes in, **ANOTHER** copy of the script will be fired up. You'd need interprocess communications of some sort to allow one http request to affect another.

Comment: You cant - the instance in the 1st execution of the script is entirely separate from the one in the second - php has a share nothing arcitechture

Comment: If you explain how this forever script works or how it's started, then you might get some useful hints on how to achieve what you want. However, given the information we have so far - it's not possible, as per previous comments.

Comment: The simpliest hack would be to trigger writing new color value to a temporary file (inside `setColor`) and read this file every time you want to display color (inside `getColor`.)

Comment: You might use some polling mechanism. 2nd request stores info in a file or db. First script with while loop polls for existence of that persistent data and if so, reads the new color from it. Exact details are based on your situation of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your "forever script" is running in its own thread regardless of anything else that's going on in the outside world. You cannot influence anything it's doing simply like that. You will need to specifically write the script to react to outside influences and offer the outside world a mechanism with which to interact with the script. There are many possibilities:

- the script reads the contents of a file on each iteration, and you write something to that file (very crude)
- same thing with a database (still crude)
- same thing with some in-memory store (better, still crude)
- you listen to a pipe or socket and write to that (better)
- you use some special interrupt signal the script listens to (getting somewhere)
- you use some asynchronous socket communication, e.g. ØMQ, Gearman or such (pretty good)

What the best method is depends on what exactly you want to achieve and what technologies you know/are willing to learn.

The term here is an "event loop". Currently you only have a "loop"; you want to get that loop to react to *events*. Events such as "contents of a file changed", "interrupt signal was received", "something was written to my pipe" etc.